# How to properly relate two mysql tables together

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables 1 for users and 1 for their posts. I have a field in both tables called user_id.

Now, if I want to pull records or have users post on my website? will I need to add a foreign key? and if so can you please explain how I can do this properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The documentation explains foreign keys in detail: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html  Where are you stuck?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: @Meenesh Jain I don't know how I should've have clarify this question but okay that's fine if you want to vote it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i got from your question:
Yes, you will need to have your POSTS.user_id to be a foreign key to USERS.user_id

USERS will look something like this:

**USERS**

user_id, user_name

**POSTS**

post_id, user_id (foreign key)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The to query you can use the query from @praveen

Answer (score 0):

From what i got from your question:
You can use INNER JOIN on the two tables.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN posts
    ON users .user_id= posts.user_id;
```

Comment: thanks bro your awesome.